# Deletion of docker image from private registry results into - The operation is unsupported

Tags: docker, devops, docker-registry

I'm trying to delete image from private docker registry using API call -

```
curl -X DELETE http://<ip>:5000/v2/lightweighttest/manifests/lightweighttest:1
```

but this results into -

```
{"errors":[{"code":"UNSUPPORTED","message":"The operation is unsupported."}]}
```

I googled for the same but it suggests to -

1. Run docker registry with flag - `REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED=true`
   but as I already have docker registry running with lot of images. This is not helpful for me
2. Make following change in config file which is located at `/var/lib/registry` or `/etc/docker/registry`
   but I could not find `registry` directory at both the locations -

   storage:
   delete:
   enabled: true

Please suggest how I can go ahead with deletion of image from private registry with running docker registry?

Comment: Did you start your registry without a volume or why can't you recreate the container?

Comment: If I recreate container, I'll loose all the data which is not my intention

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to check the registry version, only registry 2 supports the deletion of images via URL.
2. You need the location of the registry to trigger the garbage-collection. By default it's at `/etc/docker/registry/config.yml` but you can run `ps` in the container and it should be an argument of process 1.
3. If you can restart the container you can add the environment variable to the entrypoint e.g. inside the container: `sed -i -e '/exec/iexport REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED=true' entrypoint.sh`

However I'd really advise you to use a volume, because the container overflay fs has less performance, you can't upgrade and I'd suck to lose all images.